# Problemas con mi tabla

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este error, quiero mostrar en mi tabla el nombre del archivo,para que las opciones de ver y descargar, puedan ser funcionales en base a la ruta para poder abrir el archivo pdf pero para avanzar me sale el error, no se que me este fallando o que este haciendo mal, si alguien me puede instruir en este detalle se los agradeceria. La conexion es por PHP a mysqlworkbech, estoy usando xampp como server, abajo dejo el error y mi codigo html que he desarrollado

```
connect_error) { die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error); } $sql = "SELECT * FROM Documentos_Oficiales"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; } } else { echo ""; } $conn->close(); ?>
    Nombre del Documento    Visualizar  Descargar
    " . $row["nombre"] . " No se encontraron documentos
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OFICIALES.CSS" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <title>DOCUMENTOS | KRESOL</title>
</head>

<body>
    
                <h1>DOCUMENTOS OFICIALES</h1>
            </center>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="document-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre del Documento</th>
                            <th>Visualizar</th>
                            <th>Descargar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $servername = "localhost";
                        $username = "root";
                        $password = "1234";
                        $dbname = "intranet";


                        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                        if ($conn->connect_error) {
                            die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
                        }
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Documentos_Oficiales";
                        $result = $conn->query($sql);

                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><button onclick=\"visualizarPDF('" . $row["ruta"] . "')\">Visualizar</button></td>";
                                echo "<td><button onclick=\"descargarPDF('" . $row["ruta"] . "')\">Descargar</button></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">No se encontraron documentos</td></tr>";
                        }

                        $conn->close();
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Kevin, no estás mostrando las funciones de visualizarPDF y descargarPDF, pero si lo que buscas es que uno abra y el otro descargue, te conviene usar HTML5 <a href="RUTA" download>

Answer (score -2):

El código HTML que proporcionaste muestra una página web que muestra una lista de documentos oficiales con opciones para visualizar y descargar los documentos en formato PDF. El contenido de la tabla de documentos se carga dinámicamente desde una base de datos MySQL utilizando PHP.

Sin embargo, noté que hay algunos errores en el código que necesitan corrección. Específicamente, hay etiquetas de cierre innecesarias en el código que deberían eliminarse. Además, los scripts de visualización y descarga de PDFs, `visualizarPDF()` y `descargarPDF()`, no están definidos en el código proporcionado, por lo que necesitarás agregarlos si deseas que esas funciones funcionen correctamente.

Aquí está el código corregido:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OFICIALES.CSS" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <title>DOCUMENTOS | KRESOL</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>DOCUMENTOS OFICIALES</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="document-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre del Documento</th>
                    <th>Visualizar</th>
                    <th>Descargar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "1234";
                $dbname = "intranet";

                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Documentos_Oficiales";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row["nombre"] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><button onclick=\"visualizarPDF('" . $row["ruta"] . "')\">Visualizar</button></td>";
                        echo "<td><button onclick=\"descargarPDF('" . $row["ruta"] . "')\">Descargar</button></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">No se encontraron documentos</td></tr>";
                }

                $conn->close();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Aquí deberías agregar los scripts para visualizar y descargar PDFs -->
    <script>
        function visualizarPDF(ruta) {
            // Aquí puedes implementar la lógica para visualizar el PDF con la ruta proporcionada.
            // Por ejemplo, puedes abrir una nueva ventana o redirigir a un visor de PDF en línea.
        }

        function descargarPDF(ruta) {
            // Aquí puedes implementar la lógica para descargar el PDF con la ruta proporcionada.
            // Por ejemplo, puedes redirigir a la ruta del archivo PDF para que se descargue automáticamente.
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Recuerda que para que las funciones `visualizarPDF()` y `descargarPDF()` funcionen correctamente, necesitarás implementar la lógica adecuada para abrir o descargar los archivos PDF según la ruta proporcionada en la base de datos. Además, asegúrate de tener los archivos `OFICIALES.CSS` y `swiper/css/swiper.min.css` disponibles en las rutas especificadas en los enlaces de hojas de estilo CSS.

O

El error que estás encontrando está relacionado con el código PHP en tu archivo HTML. Específicamente, parece que el código PHP no se está interpretando correctamente, lo que hace que veas el código PHP real impreso en la página en lugar de la salida esperada.

Para solucionar este problema, asegúrate de ejecutar este código en un servidor que admita PHP y procese correctamente los archivos PHP. Aquí hay algunos pasos que puedes seguir para resolver el problema:

1. Asegúrate de tener PHP instalado: Verifica que tienes PHP instalado en tu servidor o entorno de desarrollo. Si PHP no está instalado, puedes descargarlo e instalarlo desde el sitio web oficial de PHP.
2. Guarda el archivo con extensión .php: Cambia el nombre de tu archivo HTML para que tenga la extensión .php. Por ejemplo, cambia el nombre del archivo a "index.php".
3. Usa un servidor PHP adecuado: Asegúrate de ejecutar el archivo en un servidor web que pueda procesar archivos PHP. Servidores web comunes como Apache o Nginx con soporte para PHP deberían funcionar bien.
4. Verifica el código PHP: Revisa el código PHP en busca de errores de sintaxis o elementos faltantes. Asegúrate de que las etiquetas PHP `<?php` y `?>` estén presentes al principio y al final del bloque de código PHP, respectivamente.
5. Ejecuta el archivo PHP: Accede al archivo PHP a través de un navegador web, por ejemplo, navegando a `http://localhost/index.php` si estás ejecutando un servidor local.

Si has seguido estos pasos y aún encuentras el problema, verifica la configuración de tu servidor y de PHP para asegurarte de que PHP esté habilitado y funcionando correctamente. Si recibes algún mensaje de error específico, eso sería útil para seguir investigando el problema.

Open AI